# C# Grid button children test

Tags: c#, loops, grid, row

I 'm really new into c# (1-2 days...). I still don't get how to access to a Grid and test if buttons inside specifics rows & columns are set to true for property "isEnabled". 
I want to test if aroud the blue button, the red one's are enabled or not.

I don't know how to write the test, to access @ the button at [ row ][ col ] (or [ i][ j ] in this case...) and his property "isEnabled".
It's a 8*8 grid with buttons. Many thanks for helping me.

```
public bool isButtonAvaible(Button button)
    {
        row = (int)button.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
        col = (int)button.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);

        foreach (Button b in gridBoard.Children)     //not sure if correct/needed

        {
            for (int i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; i++)  
            {
                for(int j = col - 1; j <= col +1; j++)
                {
                    if(gridBoard.Children ??? (Button.IsEnabledProperty ==true)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

[concept of the test on blue button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myZRL.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a test to see if a button is enabled, like you've formatted your function, it's as easy as

```
public bool isButtonAvailable(Button btn)
{
    return btn.IsEnabled;
}
```

`IsEnabled` is a Boolean property, so if you're going to pass a button as an argument to this function, you just want to return the true/false of whether the button you passed is enabled or not.  Everything else you tried - doing too much.

Comment: Maybe the name of the function is not good. In fact, I try to define if buttons  around one button are disabled. If one is disabled, then the pressed button is avaible for the user. As the buttons are stacked into a grid, I want to loop into this grid like this :

Comment: If it helped, can you upvote and accept my answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Button GetChildren(Grid grid, int row, int column)
    {
        foreach (Button child in grid.Children)
        {
            if (Grid.GetRow(child) == row
                  &&
               Grid.GetColumn(child) == column)
            {
                return child;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But it can also be more generic : `public UIElement GetChildren(etc
...){}`